# Writing the output of a process to a file which has the process id in its file name

Tags: bash, background-process, pid, io-redirection

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

- Run a command/process in background and have it's output redirected to a temporary file which is named after the process id of the background process.
- Example:

  - top &  // process Id of this background process is 1123
  - The output of top should be stored in a file 1123.temp

Is this possible? Because to truly run it in the background wouldn't we have to do the redirection before marking it as a background process? Or is there some technique to work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redirect to a temporary file and then `mv` that file to the required name e.g.

```
process > /tmp/process.log &
mv /tmp/process.log /tmp/$!.log
```

`$!` is the pid of the previously backgrounded process. Note that the mv simply renames that file. It won't interrupt writing to it.

Answer (score 2):

Running the `exec` command in bash replaces the current process (the one executing bash) with the one you're executing. So something like

```
bash -c "exec top > ${BASHPID}.temp" &
```

should work.